# How to: Share Mouse and Keyboard with 2 Computers?

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, vnc, 4k-monitor, kvm-switch

How can I create a virtual KVM Switch over the local network between two computers?

Goal: Use a 4K monitor between 2 computers.

The traditional solution is a 4K KVM Switch. But they ain't cheap.

So I figure I can just switch inputs on the monitor, and connect the mouse and keyboard to one computer. And switch over the mouse/keyboard over the network, like okvm, ICA, RDP and VNC.

What's the most practical way to accomplish this?

Comment: one option is to switch video on the monitor and switch keyboard and mouse on a cheap KVM switch (just not using its old VGA sockets).

Answer (score 1):

Look at a software solution named `Synergy`. Its home page is at http://synergy-project.org/ or https://symless.com/synergy. It will allow you to use one keyboard/mouse across multiple computers.